# Fullscreen Panel overlay in Sencha Touch 1

Tags: sencha-touch

I am trying to slide a `Panel` from the bottom, so that it covers the entire viewport, like the Bookmarks panel in iOS Safari. This is similar to the `ActionSheet`, but fulscreen, and without the dark frame around it.

```
this.advSearch = Ext.ComponentMgr.create({xtype: 'advanced_search', itemId: 'pnlAdvancedSearch'});
this.advSearch.autoRender = true;
this.advSearch.show({type: 'slide', direction: 'up'});
```

This sort of works, but the new panel doesn't fill the whole screen, and parts of it appear behind the background panel. I've tried various layouts, including `fit`, `vbox`, with varying degrees of ugliness, but the root problem seems to be that the panel doesn't know how tall it needs to be. Maybe because it doesn't have a container?

Any suggestions? Is this even the right approach, or should I try to hack the ActionSheet to expand to fullscreen, and show without the border?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your panel is floating (or I presume it is), you will need to give the panel a fixed height in Sencha Touch 1. You are very restricted in that respect. This following code should work:

```
var sheet = new Ext.Sheet({
    html: 'hello',
    style: 'color:#fff',
    height: window.innerHeight,
    stretchX: true
});

// replace this show with your animation
sheet.show();
```

As you can see, I give it a fixed height of the window and then stretch it on the X axis (y doesn't work).